# Error connecting to SSL server using C# and .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I'm trying to do a fairly basic SSL connection and I'm hitting a brick wall as to why it doesn't work. It connects fine over HTTP, but not HTTPS. **This only happens for a set of sites.** It works fine for google.com for example, but this particular server is running a LetsEncrypt certificate. Could it be because of that?

Code for **ssltest.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SSLTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string result = wc.DownloadString("https://healthstone.ca/");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /out:ssltest.exe ssltest.cs
```

Run:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at SSLTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It works fine if I change the site to http. The site also loads fine in a browser. The 2 `ServicePointManager` lines I added based on previous questions I found on similar issues, but no dice. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

```
Protocols Supported
TLS 1.2   Yes
TLS 1.1   Yes
TLS 1.0   No
SSL 3     No
SSL 2     No
```

So that site allows TLS version 1.1 or 1.2 but does not support TLS 1.0.

You need to:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This requires .Net 4.5+.

Comment: This solved it! Still curious why it wouldn't attempt TLS by default, compiling on Windows 8. Why is it just throwing an exception..

Comment: If you try your code with the URL `https://www.ssllabs.com` and just `.Ssl3` it fails nicely with  *`Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`* because they don't support it. If you look at the test results for `healthstone.ca` you can see several *"server closed connection"* messages so it looks like they are hammering connections that dont implement a supported protocol rather than allowing the client negotiation phase to complete.

Comment: It's actually my server running a default CentOS 7/Apache/LetsEncrypt configuration. I'm unsure why it wouldn't fail gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on an older Windows 2008 server. Internet explorer on the server was also unable to open the URL. Firefox was able to open the URL.

Windows 2008 and the Schannel service only supports TLS 1.0, and the Hitch TLS endpoint I was targeting only had TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 enabled.

I resolved it by enabling TLS 1.0 on the endpoint.